# Making multiple JQuery AJAX calls from a single event

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following event called Submit() but currently this event is only making 1 AJAX POST call, can I make multiple AJAX on success of the first call all in a single event?

```
function Submit() {
if (isValidSubmit()) {
    var input = BuildInputXML();
    var svc = parent.svc;
    var uid = parent.uid();
    var ajax_url = svc + "/DR_DRStep7.svc/InsertSpdDist";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_url,
        data: "{\"input\": \"" + input + "\", \"planner\": \"" + parent.userID + "\"}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processdata: true,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.InsertSpdDistResult) {
                alert("Spd Distribution Data Saved!");
                $("#cmdSubmit").attr('disabled', true);
                displaySummary();
                // Call another function that makes an AJAX call
                GetUpdatedData();
            } else {
                alert('Failed to Insert Spd Distribution for data: ' + parent.data);
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: have u tried it? give it a try. You can have multiple ajax call in single event

Comment: yes you can make it multiple ajax in single submit, look at the docs

Comment: Hi, I wanted to make another AJAX call on success of the first call, but that doesn't seem to work :-(

Comment: OK, I have added another function called GetUpdatedData() and this function will make an AJAX call, is this the right way to do this?

Comment: yes that is ok but AJAX calls are `async` in nature. so best way is to handle it with `promises`

Comment: Hi Anto J Subash, I'm new to AJAX, what do you mean by with "promises"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajax_url,
    data: "{\"input\": \"" + input + "\", \"planner\": \"" + parent.userID + "\"}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    processdata: true,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.InsertSpdDistResult) {
            alert("Spd Distribution Data Saved!");
            $("#cmdSubmit").attr('disabled', true);
            displaySummary();
        } else {
            alert('Failed to Insert Spd Distribution for data: ' + parent.data);
        }
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

try to put this piece of code in for or while loop

Comment: Some bug in the GetUpdatedData() function. The code is working now and the call is async as mentioned by Anto.